# VBNet BackGroundWorker passing argument in RunWorkerCompleted Event

Tags: .net, vb.net, backgroundworker

my current solution as you can see is by using shared variable within a class in order to pass a value.

on the form load of my application i called: `workerSample.RunWorkerAsync`

```
Dim finalList As List(Of String)
Private Sub workerSample_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles workerSample.DoWork
    Dim xList As New List(Of String)
    'long process of finding folder which contains executable files
    finalList = xList
End Sub

Private Sub workerSample_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles workerSample.RunWorkerCompleted
    'do something with finalList
End Sub
```

is there another way to pass `xList` variable to `RunWorkerCompleted` by using an argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim finalList As List(Of String)

Private Sub workerSample_DoWork(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles workerSample.DoWork
    Dim xList As New List(Of String)
    e.Result = xList
End Sub

Private Sub workerSample_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles workerSample.RunWorkerCompleted
    Me.finalList = e.Result
End Sub
```